# Retrieving a DbSyncScopeDescription object from the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

When I provision a table with sync framework I use the `DbSyncScopDescription` object to add tables to the scope. Now after shutting down the program I want to retrieve my `DbSyncScopeDescription` objects from the database to be loaded in the following:

```
private static Dictionary<string,DbSyncScopeDescription> scopes { get; set; }
```

I want to call a `load()` method that will fill the dictionary when I start-up the program to know what a scopes are available (the easy part) and retrieve the scope description objects to control the scope (the hard part form me).

I figured that I can use the `scope_info` table in the database to get the name of the scopes back but I do not know what to do after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the scope names, you loop thru the list of scopes and call GetDescriptionForScope for each scope name